# Tensorflow non-discrete / continuous class lables

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to use non-one-hot vectors with tensorflow? ie. can i give it class labels that are continuous, such as [1.2, 5.98, 2.1] ?
I'm very new to this, so apologies if this isn't very clear - I have a bunch of images, and want each to be associated to a vector of 3 continuous values, such that I can generate images with some given three values later.. 
Any help/pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Is the problem to learn a continuous function (regression) or discrete function (classification)? Is the problem to predict 3 values, give an input image?

Comment: Problem is to learn a continuous function.

Comment: For the second question - the other way around - given 3 values, I want an image generated

Comment: What kind of algorithm are you using? This looks like more of a modeling/algorithm question than an implementation/tensorflow question. Tensorflow is quite general and could be used both for regression and classification.

Comment: Ah i see, thank you, that clarifies things - I wasn't entirely sure where I should be looking to figure this out